# When is quotient of semi-direct product by commutator Z^n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G := \mathbb{Z} \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^{n - 1}$ be given via some homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow {\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^{n - 1})$, s.t. $G$ is non-abelian.

**Question:** Is there a possibility for
$\mathbb{Z}^n \cong G/[G,G]$ (isomorphism of groups) to hold except for $\varphi$ being the trivial homomorphism?

Comment: I guess I found a solution implying the answer is "no". Following  [[MO35713](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35713/abelianization-of-a-semidirect-product)], we get that

$G/[G,G] \cong \mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}^{n - 1})_\mathbb{Z}$

where

$(\mathbb{Z}^{n - 1})_\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}^{n - 1}/<\varphi(k)x - x, k \in\mathbb{Z}, x \in \mathbb{Z}^{n - 1}>$

Comment: Let $H$ denote the subgroup generated by $\varphi(k)x - x$ for $k \in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{n - 1}$. If $H$ is non-trivial, $(\mathbb{Z}^{n - 1})_\mathbb{Z} \not\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$. But $H = \{e\}$ only if $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow {\rm id}_{\mathbb{Z}^{n - 1}}$. Comments welcome!